# Sending an aknwoledgment in LUA UDP server

Tags: sockets, lua, udp

I am working on a LUA acknowledgment for a udp message being sent from a webpage,
so if the webpage sends me an 's' I should do something, in addition to send an ACK. I am able to receive the message, but not able to reply to it.

```
CadUDPSocketIN = assert(socket.udp()) 
assert(CadUDPSocketIN:settimeout())
assert(CadUDPSocketIN:setsockname("192.168.13.31", 3033)) 

while true do  
    datain = CadUDPSocketIN:receive()
    if(datain) then
      ip1, port1 = CadUDPSocketIN:getpeername()
      udp_c = assert(socket.udp())
      assert(udp_c:setpeername(ip1, port1))
      udp_c:send("Ack")
        if (datain == 's') then  
           --Do something
        end

    end
```

Comment: In what sense are you "not able" to reply?  Do you see the reply when you capture packets on the server?

Comment: I am waiting for any kind of "string" Acknowledgment on the the server side, but nothing is received

Comment: I would suggest breaking out wireshark, on both sides.

Comment: The problem is I am using LUA on an embedded system that wireshark wouldn't work with.

Comment: there should be a colon instead of dot? -> `udp_c:send("Ack")`

Comment: @Eng_Mike wireshark doesn't need to be right on the machine being sniffed... with an Ethernet hub, or a switch that supports port mirroring, and it can run on a different machine.  But the comment above this one also seems to make a point that I overlooked.

Comment: @pkisztelinski , yes you are right. I've changed it, but still nothing

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I see, OK thanks, I will be trying that.